# Changing the colour of the grey "border" on input[type=text]

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to change the colour of the grey "border" around a text input without changing the border thickness using CSS?

I initially thought that using `border-color` would allow me to change the colour, however, as seen in the image / code example below, changing the colour also appears to make the border thicker. I would like to keep the default width (2px) but change the colour of the border.

The image is a zoomed in screenshot of the code snippet below to highlight the apparent change in border thickness when the colour is changed.

[image]

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

input[type=text] {
  flex: 1 1 0;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}

.different_color {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text" class="different_color">
</div>
```

---

**Edit**

To clarify, the default border, which according to the developer console has a `border-width` of 2px appears to be rendered as only part of the 2px whilst still essentially padding the content in by a fixed 2px. However, when I set a colour on the border, it no longer renders only this small part, but the whole 2px. The image below shows this with the left side of the image being the default border and the right side of the image being the border with the `border-color` set to red.

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate the issue and what you want to achieve ?

Comment: It seems that setting the color also resets the width. If you look in Layout under your browser inspector you will see the default border width is 1. By setting the color it resets to 2. The quickfix would be to set it manually with `border-width:1px`

Comment: there is no border-thickness. it's border-width

Comment: @Manjuboyz I'd just like to change the colour of the border from grey to another colour, red in this example, without changing it's thickness. I could set the border thickness to 0.5px or whatever, but that then adjusts the size of the box which I don't want to do. The default grey border seems to be 2px thick but only a slither of it is actually grey and the rest is white (if you hover over the border in the inspector, you will see it is thicker than the grey section)

Comment: and there is a default border-style set to inset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the `border-color` will not change the `border-width` per se.

But you might have noticed that form elements by default looks different on MacOS than on Windows 10. That is because unstyled form elements are rendered using platform native styling. If you inspect an unstyled `<input>` in Chrome or Firefox and view the browser applied rulesets, you will see the input has `-webkit-appearance: textfield` or `-moz-appearance: textfield` respectively. This makes the browser apply these platform specific styles which will override even the browser defaults.

(In Firefox you can play around with the `appearance` property and make a `<div>` render as a native styled input element and make a `<span>` look like a button by adding the `appearance` property like the following snippet demonstrates)

```css
div {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
  appearance: textfield;
}
span {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  -moz-appearance: button;
  appearance: button;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<span></span>
```

What happens once you start styling a form element is that the `appearance` ruleset will be removed and the browser will apply the browser defaults instead. As for the input element, it has `border-style: inset` and `border-width: 2px` by default in Chrome. That is what you are seeing. That is why the width and style changes once you change the color. And that is why you can't just change the border color.

You will have to manually "style your way back" to simulate the platform native form element.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work in Chromium based browsers at all. Thanks! Added a note it only works in Firefox

Comment: Same thing says [CanIUse.com](https://caniuse.com/#search=appearance). Seems like my Brave browser is using Chromium 80

Comment: Seems like Brave is still using 81 at latest version which is partially supported.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's ashame it doesn't seem possible to change the native component border colour. Ah well. I'll mark your answer correct in the next few days but for now will leave the question open to see if anyone has a way of doing it

Answer (score 0):

As *@sergiu reznicencu* said,

> it seems that setting the color also resets the width.
>
> By setting the color it resets to 2.

Different browsers also seem to show different values for browser width. Some say 1px and some 2px while border is actually less than 1px wide.

Default value, according to [W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-width.asp) and [Mozilla developers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-width), initial (default value) is medium. If you do set a border with `border-width: medium`, it will be thicker than default one.

```css
input {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.custom-clr-only {
  border-color: red;
}

.custom {
  border: medium solid green;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
<input type="text" class="custom-clr-only">
<input type="text" class="custom">
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I do not want to change the width of the border

Comment: Thanks for the response. I didn't say I don't want to specify the width. I meant I don't want to change it from 2px (which is set in my CSS in the question). Also which reference mentions you **have to** set the border-width if you want a custom border?

Comment: Thanks for the response and sorry to be a pain, but if you zoom in on the results of your answer (the grey and red borders) you can see they are different thicknesses which is what the question is about. It's really strange that this is an issue

Comment: @Dan seems like that first (default) border is 0.5px wide

Comment: Yeah, it's odd. But in the inspector, at least for me, it definitely says it is 2px thick. Which is what is causing my confusion

Comment: @Dan it varies from browser to browser. However just simply set border width with color :)

Comment: Hi, I'm afraid I do not think your answer answers my question, apologies. However, I have removed the section about outline to avoid confusion and thanks for making it clear they are two seperate things

Answer (score 0):

You also have to specify the border style :

```
.specialborder{
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

[image: ImageWIthBorderStyle]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I do not want to change the width of the border